# Japanese text as mail body

Tags: java, apache-camel, jakarta-mail

I am also running into a problem while sending mail body in japanese.

I have used the MimeUtility.encodeText(subject, "utf-8", "B"), but this only works for Subject not for japanese text in mail body.

```
headerMap.put("Subject", MimeUtility.encodeText(transmissionMessage.getSubject(), 
"UTF-8", "B"));
headerMap.put("ContentType", "text/html");
msg.setHeaders(headerMap);
msg.setBody(transmissionMessage.getBody());
```

I am using apache camel for mail.

Please help

Comment: Try ContentType text/html;charset=utf-8

Comment: What do "a problem" and "only works for Subject" specifically mean?

Comment: By problem, I mean MimeUtility.encodeText(transmissionMessage.getBody(), 
"UTF-8", "B") does not work for japanese text whereas MimeUtility.encodeText(transmissionMessage.getSubject(), 
"UTF-8", "B") works for Japanese text

Answer (score 2):

Problem resolved with

```
exchange.setProperty(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never need to encode the text yourself.  Use the MimeMessage setSubject and MimeBodyPart setText methods that allow you to specify the charset to use.